# possible to get return of records NOT in db? mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose, nosql

Sorry I do not have a script here, but what I wanted to do is.

Let's say I have some unique array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
and my db only has record of `1, 2, 3, 5`

Is there a way for mongoose to compare and have an output such as `4` is not in DB, but without doing changes such as `create, update`

I can do it through the long way to query and the DB with `$in` to get what's in DB then compare records returned.

But I wonder if there'll be a faster way through mongoose?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / help.

Comment: did you tried `array.includes(4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const database = [1, 2, 3, 5]

const notInDB = arr.filter(value => {
  return database.indexOf(value) === -1
})

console.log(notInDB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method to find what is in db and then compare the result with your array to get what is not in your db.

Example:

```
async () => {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let inDb = await YourModel.distinct("your_field");
  let notInDb = arr.filter(val => !inDb.includes(val));
}
```